# Layout Animation on Transforms

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native 0.30 with Android. I'm trying to apply Layout Animation on transform properties like:

```
transform: [
  { scale: scaleSize },
  { rotateY: rotation }
]
```

But, it's not animating somehow. Other properties like `left` or `right` etc are animating. Is there anything wrong I'm doing? Or isn't it possible to animate transform properties with Layout Animation?

Comment: What is your completed code? Can you add it on Rnplay. Above code is just for style it won't created animation.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I want to use it to animate a view, when a value inside it changes. I think I might need to use Animated instead of LayoutAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

For scale animation, you need to use customized animation.

```
LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
  duration: 700,
  create: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.scaleXY,
  },
  update: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.spring,
    springDamping: 0.4,
  },
  delete: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.scaleXY,
  },
}
```

Example: https://rnplay.org/apps/JbdOpQ and https://github.com/vinceyuan/ReactNativeOpacityBugDemo